# Inspect Mobile Edge For Android

Tags: android, web-applications, microsoft-edge

Have a web app that gets stuck on the loading screen on Edge for Android (42.0.0.2059)

Works fine emulating the device on Edge windows, Edge for iOS, Android Chrome etc. Is there any way to inspect whats going on?

Thanks, Lewis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should now be supported;

https://twitter.com/MWautier/status/1024731673433268224